# Leaflet svg after update event

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I am trying to add some decorations to some polygons/poly-lines, I have some code (using d3) that gets the items from the svg element in leaflet, generates some graphics based on the paths coordinates and then adds them to the svg element.

Obviously on zoom, this breaks as the leaflet polygons/poly-lines update coordinates so I am trying to find an event that is called after the svg layer is recalculated, as on('zoomend') seems to be triggered before the recalc, same with on('viewreset').

I am guessing I have to listen to events on the svg renderer, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a slightly clunky workaround

`.on('zoomend')` I am removing the decorations, then I am setting a timeout for 10ms that adds them back in. It appears to be working (though the decorations visually disappear then reappear, not the end of the world but will be looking for a fix)

I don't like the "timer" based nature of this but with a lack of a better solution I may not have a choice.

one options may be to alter the path on zoom instead of re-draw.